# Spaces Changed to Whitespace

Tags: php, regex, space

The code below produces an unexpected result:

```
$row = 'one        //There are spaces here
two  ';
$row = explode(PHP_EOL,$row);
$row = $row[0];
preg_match('/( +)$/',$row,$matches);
```

When using `var_dump($matches);`, the output is:

```
array(0) {
}
```

But, it should be something like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>string(8) "        "
    [1]=>string(8) "        "
}
```

- Replacing `PHP_EOL` with `"\n"` makes no difference.
- Using `preg_match('/(\s+)$/',$row,$matches);` produces the expected result:

  ```
  array(2) {
      [0]=>string(8) "        "
      [1]=>string(8) "        "
  }
  ```
- The expected also happens when using:

  ```
  $row = 'one        ';
  preg_match('/( +)$/',$row,$matches);
  ```

But, obviously, these both have their own reasons to not be used.

My question is: *Why does PHP not recognize the spaces as spaces but only as whitespace?*

*Example:* http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6f3ea8b422671d86a37b765986395b1dd6f94e8

Comment: The code is working on my system. I copy/pasted your example (just removed the // and following from line 1) and I can reproduce the correct behavior. Maybe you should update your PHP? (I don't know if that could have been a bug in a previous version)

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: 5.5.8 on OSX Mavericks

Comment: It's happening for me on versions `5.2.17` and `5.5.5`.  Here's an example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6f3ea8b422671d86a37b765986395b1dd6f94e8  It doesn't work whether the comment is in or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"\n\r"` instead of `PHP_EOL` or space

```
$row = explode("\n\r",$row);
$row = $row[0];
preg_match('/( +)$/',$row,$matches);
```

Now as you see you can use space in pattern for regExp

Comment: Actually, the reverse order seemed to work for me.  I thought `"\n"` would cover such a possibility but I guess I was wrong.  I don't understand why `PHP_EOL` doesn't work, but I guess it is because of a similar reason.  Thank you.  Just swap the order and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Actually I think it's because of the version of PHP you have, check this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)